# How to install Python 2.5.4 in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: installation, 11.10, python

I've been reading through some posts on how to install Python 2.5.4 in Ubuntu but I can not manage to find a solution to my problem. The version of Ubuntu I have is the 11.10 and the one of Python I intend to install is 2.5.4. It must be that one and not any of the updates since I am following a course which  uses specifically 2.5.4. I have already tried executing in the terminal commands proposed in other posts but I always get a mistake.

I'd be really thankful I some could explain detailed and concisely how I can do it.

As said, thank you in advance,

Dionisio.

Comment: @Mitch is that PPA available for Ubuntu 11.10 ?

Comment: @Jai you mean the one from the second answer? Yes, but I'm referring to Rinzwind's answer.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that too. we can close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and do these steps one by one.

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.4/Python-2.5.4.tar.bz2
tar -zxvf Python-2.5.4.tgz
 cd Python-2.5.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

that will install Python 2.5.4 in your Ubuntu.

hope that helps.